# Input a programs arguments using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I need to run a program that requires an argument as an input

I tried the following method....

```
set /p Input = Select YouTube Video URL:

cd C:\youTube  (location of program)

program.exe %Input%
```

The program tries to run but does not like the argument of %Input%.
Is there a special way of passing an argument to a program ? I have tried with and without quotes

Comment: Remove the spaces around the `=`. Does that help?

Comment: Yes !! - Thanks that fixed it

Comment: Helps when you read the help file for the command you are trying to use. You would see plain as day the syntax usage does not show any spaces.